# share post through facebook app from my website not working

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to share a post on facebook from my website. I do on a desktop that`s fine, but if click on the share button in mobile phone then shares the post through facebook app.
I used this facebook protocol ==> fb://sharer/?link=,
in that Facebook app is open but not share the post. 
How can I send a post through facebook app from my website.

```
<a class="icona" href="fb://sharer/?link=<?php echo $link; ?>"><img src="icons/facebook.png" width="50px;">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: why not use sharer.php?

Comment: where?   fb://sharer.php/... like that

Comment: If you don’t want this to use the mobile app, but just be handled by the user’s browser, then use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#advancedtopics

Comment: working on a browser is perfect but not through the app.